# Is There a Ping Etiquette for Checking Connections

Tags: ping

I use two Raspberry Pis to feed four separate flight tracking sites.  These RPis are setup to ping my wireless router first, then Google twice an hour just to ensure that they have a connection.  If either or both pings fail, a log entry is created in a custom text file, and in the case of a failure to ping the wireless router, the wifi service is restarted.  I would like to have these RPis ping more than twice an hour per RPi, but do not want to be rude.  Is there a ping etiquette for pinging to check connection status?  I'm not planning on pinging every minute, but if I did, that would be 120 pings per hour/2,880 ping per 24-hour period for the combined two RPis which run 24/7.

Comment: Welcome! I added an answer but I'm not sure why you need to know if you have network connectivity to reach out. Why doesn't your program just try to do the feed and see if it errors?

Comment: That amount of ping is fine. Have you considered connecting to port 443 of google instead of pinging? You can use netcat `nc -vz -w5 www.google.com 443`

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a guideline for this but I think it's clear that 120 pings per hour is not malicious.

You could probably do quite a bit faster with no one really caring depending on the administrator.

One option you have is to just use more servers as your internet test targets. DNS servers frequently respond to pings and if you are polite you can get a pretty constant rate for your tests:

A quick search came up with these:

```
Cisco OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220;
Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1;
Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4; and
Quad9: 9.9.9.9 and 149.112.112.112.
```

With just that you could do eight times what you currently do without changing anything else.